# input contains NaN when i'm trying to train model

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

Could you tell me how to fix the error
I use decisiontree to train the model of the stroke.
dataset is on kaggle , but.. i don't understand this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:,[0,12]].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,13].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
SC = StandardScaler()
X = SC.fit_transform(X)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy")
classifier.fit(X,Y)
```

and this is the error:[image]

My train.csv : https://www.kaggle.com/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset

Comment: You should analyse your data and drop or replace missing data. Something like X=X.fillna(X.median()) could do the trick depending on your data.

Comment: By inspecting the data from the given link, I could see that there are missing values in the bmi column. Try imputing the data with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what data I'm using, but to remove Nan, add the following

x_train = x_train.dropna()

I hope you can answer your question

Comment: Is it really the best idea to simply drop nulls whenever you see them? There could be useful information encoded in those nulls – it's just a matter of finding the best way to handle such data.

Comment: Not the best idea... Check for instance https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

Answer (score 0):

Many scikit-learn estimators (e.g. the decision tree model you're trying to use) do not natively support null (`np.nan`) types. So, you need to handle those `NaN`s somehow before feeding your dataset to the estimator. You could 1) drop any cases where null values exist (*not necessarily the best idea!*), or 2) apply some sort of imputation scheme to fill those null values with some reasonable value. Option number 2 is often preferred as there could be good reason for nulls in your dataset (i.e. there could be good information from which your model may benefit contained in those nulls).

For more on imputation and scikit-learn, read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html).

Notably, you're able to "pass" the `StandardScaler` section without error because, as is mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> NaNs are treated as missing values: disregarded in fit, and maintained in transform.

So while those NaNs are ignored when fitting the scaler, they are preserved in transformation.

For detail on whether to scale before or after imputation, read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138203/imputation-of-missing-data-before-or-after-centering-and-scaling). But since you're using a tree-based model and scaling is a monotonic transformation (i.e. it doesn't affect the ranking of the data), you don't really need to apply scaling at all.

And finally, there are *some* scikit-learn estimators which natively handle NaNs (no imputation required), e.g. [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html).